# Selenium WDS executeScript()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I have a strange problem, which I'm unable to solve for sometime. I have a selenium WDS for Firefox browser. I tried to execute the code in JMeter UI, everything works fine. But when I try to execute the same in a server (using XVFB driver), I get the error:

**rm="sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Can't find method org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(string,org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement). (<Unknown source>#17) in <Unknown source> at line number 17"**

All the required drivers are the same as the one I locally try. Yet, I get the error only when I run in the server but not locally.  Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you have different versions of either [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) or dependency libraries, I don't see any other ways for the same script to work on one machine and don't work on another.

1. Install the same version of JMeter onto both machines (use [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32) or later, whatever is available at [JMeter Downloads Page](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi))
2. Install latest version of the WebDriver Sampler plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
3. Your test should now be running fine.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T. Installing both the latest version of JMeter and the WebDriver Sampler worked.